# Binary Max Heap Problem for two different results

Tags: java, sorting, heapsort, binary-heap

I am trying to learn about binary heaps and I tried to implement a max binary heap. Following is the code I wrote.

```
public class MaxBinaryHeap {
    
    private int size;
    
    int[] heap;
    
    

    public MaxBinaryHeap(int size) {
        
        this.size = size;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //creating a heap
        MaxBinaryHeap binaryHeap = new MaxBinaryHeap(20);
        
        //adding elements to heap array
        binaryHeap.add(2);
        binaryHeap.add(7);
        binaryHeap.add(26);
        binaryHeap.add(25);
        binaryHeap.add(19);
        binaryHeap.add(17);
        binaryHeap.add(1);
        binaryHeap.add(90);
        binaryHeap.add(3);
        binaryHeap.add(36);
        
        //calling this method to reorganize the heap array
        binaryHeap.heap();
        
    }



    private void heap() {
        int size = heap.length;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(heap));
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
              //following is call to another heap method - commented
            //heapify2(heap)

            heapify(heap);
        }
        
    }


    //method to add elements in heap array
    private void add(int i) {
        
        if(heap==null) {
            heap = new int[1];
            heap[0]=i;
        }
        else {
            int[] arr = new int[heap.length+1]; 
            for(int x=0;x<heap.length;x++) {
                arr[x]=heap[x];
            }
            arr[heap.length]=i;
            heap=arr;
            
            
            
        }
        
    }


    //the sorting in this method starts from the beginning
    private void heapify(int[] heap) {
        int size = heap.length;
        for(int i=0;i<(size/2);i++) {
            int child1=2*i+1;
            if(child1<size) {
                if(heap[child1] > heap[i]) {
                    int temp = heap[i];
                    heap[i]=heap[child1];
                    heap[child1]=temp;
                }
            }
            int child2=2*i+2;
            if(child2<size) {
                if(heap[child2] > heap[i]) {
                    int temp = heap[i];
                    heap[i]=heap[child2];
                    heap[child2]=temp;
                }
            }
            
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(heap));
        
    }
    
   //the sorting in this method starts from the end
    private void heapify2(int[] heap) {
        int size = heap.length;
        for(int i=(size/2);i>-1;i--) {
            int child1=2*i+1;
            if(child1<size) {
                if(heap[child1] > heap[i]) {
                    int temp = heap[i];
                    heap[i]=heap[child1];
                    heap[child1]=temp;
                }
            }
            int child2=2*i+2;
            if(child2<size) {
                if(heap[child2] > heap[i]) {
                    int temp = heap[i];
                    heap[i]=heap[child2];
                    heap[child2]=temp;
                }
            }
            
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(heap));
        
    }

}
```

So Here are the questions I have,

1. How many times do I actually need to call heaping method, in the following method I called heapify method 10 times, equal to size of array, but it sorted the array in about 3-4 iterations,so what's the minimal count of calling heapify method.

   ```
          private void heap() {
            int size = heap.length;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(heap));
            //calling heapify method 
             for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
            heapify(heap);
           }

         }
   ```
2. When I call `heapify2()` method the output I got was

   ```
          Input: [2, 7, 26, 25, 19, 17, 1, 90, 3, 36]

          Output:[90, 36, 26, 7, 25, 17, 1, 2, 3, 19]

                               90
                              /   \
                            36     26
                           / \     / \
                          7   25   17  1
                         / \  /
                        2  3  19
   ```

and when I called `heapify()` method the output I got was

```
          Input: [2, 7, 26, 25, 19, 17, 1, 90, 3, 36]

          Output:[90, 36, 17, 25, 26, 7, 1, 2, 3, 19]

                               90
                              /   \
                            36     17
                           / \     / \
                          25  26  7   1
                         / \  /
                        2  3  19
```

These two methods produce two different binary heaps, I wonder if they are correct and is there a better way to build heap. will deeply appreciate your help on this, thanks in advance.